# stuck at this Rolle's theorem exercise

Tags: calculus

> Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R_{+}^{*}}$ and $f$ derivative in $[a,b]$. Show that: $\exists c\in (a,b)$:
>
> $$\frac{f\left ( b \right )}{f\left ( a \right )}=\frac{{f}'\left ( c \right )}{f\left ( c \right )}e^{b-a}$$

I tried my best and arrived here : 
$${\ln [f(c)]}'-\frac{f(b)}{e^{b}}\frac{1}{\frac{f(a)}{e^{a}}}=0$$

I would love to hear some ideas or hints. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: By derivable you mean differentiable?

Comment: I'm just curious why you don't want to use the symbol $[a,b]$

Comment: @LoganLuther admit a derived function

Comment: @juniven satisfied now ?

Comment: Yes I am, thank you.

Comment: Apply mean value theorem on $\log f(x)$ in $[a, b]$.

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your question. The expression should be $$\frac{f(b)}{f(a)} = \exp\left((b - a)\cdot\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}\right)$$ The question as it stands is wrong and one can check by putting $f(x) = 1$ when LHS is $1$ and RHS is $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sorry to disappoint you but what i typed is completly correct

Comment: It may be the given statement, but Paramanand Singh gave you a simple counterexample to show that it cannot be _true_.

Comment: Ok then the typo is not from your side, but it is fault of the book. There can be typos and mistakes in books too and luckily mathematics is a subject where you can ensure (without much effort) that there is a mistake / typo in book.

Answer (score 1):

I had an answer using the same hint as suggested by Paramanand Singh in the comments but that doesn't give the required result. He points out that this is probably a typo, so I'll post this suggestion anyway.

You can derive the Mean Value Theorem (MVT) from Rolle's theorem. Apply it to the function $g$ where $g(x) = \ln f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ to get, for a certain $c \in \; ]a,b[$:
$$g(b)-g(a) = (b-a)g'(c) \implies \ln f(b) - \ln f(a) = (b-a)\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}$$
Now the left-hand side is $\ln\tfrac{f(b)}{f(a)}$, so applying the exponential function to both sides gives:
$$\frac{f(b)}{f(a)} = \exp\left( (b-a)\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)} \right)$$
Which is not what you wrote, but what might be the intented answer.

Comment: i wish it was a typo but its not . what i typed there is completly correct

Comment: It may be the given statement, but Paramanand Singh gave you a simple counterexample (the constant function $f(x)=1$) to show that it cannot be _true_.

Comment: oh well i don't know at that point . so what you mean is my question has no solution

Comment: I mean the statement as given is _false_, so it cannot be proven.